# VBA email code triggered by Cell Value based off of a Formula

Tags: excel, vba, email, excel-formula

I am extremely new to VBAs in Excel and just copied this code I found on the internet. The issue is that currently the email is only sent if the value in Column Q is changed manually to 30 however, I have a formula that I use for this cell number to auto update (its a running day count) so I would like it to trigger the VBA based off of the formula and not having to manually enter the value into the cell.
Any help would be great!

```
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  Set xRg = Intersect(Range("Q2:Q6000"), Target)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value = 30 Then
        Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Range("A" & Target.Row).Value)
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook(mailSubject As String)
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "mail body"
    On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "email"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = mailSubject
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Send   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim xI As Integer
Dim xRg As Range
Set xRg = Range("Q2:Q6000")
On Error GoTo Err01
xI = Int(xRg.Value)
If xI = 30 Then
Call Mail_small_Text_Outlook(Range("A" & Target.Row).Value)
End If
Err01:
End Sub
```

Comment: This approach might send an email multiple times for the same value - every time your workbook calculates.  That's probably not what you want.  Plus in your `Calculate` event handler you have no `Target` to restrict the range to scan, so multiple cells in Q2:Q6000 might be >30: what should happen then?

Comment: I do want an email trigger for every time a value in Column Q is = 30. If it is > 30 or < 30 I do not want an email generated.

Comment: What if the sheet calculates five times and no values change during the recalculation? E.g. lets say the same 5 cells are  = 30 at the end of each calculation:  would you really want  one mail for each cell (so 25 mails), or one mail listing all cells (5 mails) ?

Comment: The formula is a running day count so when each Cell in the row hits 30, I would like an email from that cell but only running once per day. The next day it will be 31 so it should not trigger an email for that cell. This should only be relevant for the values in column Q. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Const CHECK_RANGE As String = "Q2:Q6000"
    Const INFO_COL As String = "A" 'info for the email
    Const FLAG_COL As String = "R" 'column to store "sent mail" date
    
    Dim c As Range, v, dt
    For Each c In Me.Range(CHECK_RANGE).Cells
        v = c.Value
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            If v = 30 Then
                'already sent a mail today?
                If c.EntireRow.Columns(FLAG_COL).Value <> Date Then
                    c.EntireRow.Columns(FLAG_COL).Value = Date 'record send date
                    Debug.Print c.Address 'for testing
                    'Mail_small_Text_Outlook c.EntireRow.Columns(INFO_COL).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

If should only send one mail per cell per day.

Comment: This does work to trigger an email to send! However I had to replace the top section with this code otherwise it sent me continuous emails. Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the top section" ?  "continuous mails" was what I was warning about in my comments above if you use the `Calculate` event to trigger the alerts.

Comment: Nvm that part I figured out but ya if I can only get 1 email per cell value that would be the best. I only used the `Calculate`  function because it was mentioned in another thread to work..

Comment: If you add a "mail sent" column to your sheet you could add the date when you send a mail for a row - check that the next time it runs and if it's today's date don't re-send the mail.

Comment: See my updates above.

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately that won't really work with the spreadsheet I currently have. The email is more of a reminder for myself to follow up with an address that has been active for 30 days.